# Dependency on master and child in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a master table like this

```
Product    Status  Product id
A          True     1
B          True     2
C          true     3
D          True     4
E          false    5
F          True     6
```

Now I have other table which is giving me the dependency of the product

```
Product    DependencyId
C             2
C             5
E             1
B             4
B             6
```

Now when I searching for C, I can see that two products are dependent upon C now these two product is dependent upon other products.

And let say I am searching for E, then I there are only one dependency of the product.

Now, I need to check for a product that if any dependency is false or not. If any of the dependency is false then I have to return some text/value.

**Result**

```
When product is C then output will be E (because the grand children of C (i.e. E) has false)

When product is B then output will be NULL (becuase none of the child of B or their sub childrens has false)
```

Comment: Please give an example of what you want, using the sample data you have supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @cnt int

Select * 
into #tmp
from mastera where Product_ID in (Select DependencyID from dbo.dependency where Product='C')

select @cnt=0
while @cnt<>(Select count(*) from #tmp)
begin 
    Select @cnt=count(*) from #tmp
    insert into #tmp
    Select m.* 
    from mastera m
    Left join  #tmp on m.Product=#tmp.Product 
    where m.Product_ID in (Select DependencyID from dbo.dependency where Product in (Select Product from #tmp where status=1))
    and #tmp.Product is null
end


Select * from #tmp  where Status=0

Drop table #tmp
```

Comment: I am getting this error while running this script *An explicit value for the identity column in table '#tmp' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.*

Comment: Oh ! my master table was having a identity column also. now instead of select * at the top now I am using only required columns..

Comment: but now at this step   Select @cnt=count(*) from #tmp
    insert into #tmp
, I am getting this *Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.*

Answer (score 0):

This should list the immediate children with a *false* status.

```
SELECT  
    C.Product
FROM 
    MasterTable A
JOIN
    Dependency D ON D.Product = A.Product
JOIN
    MasterTable C ON C.ProductId = D.DependencyId AND C.Status = 0
```